# Installing MS SQL Server on Centos

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, centos

Has anyone been able to install SQL Server on Centos 6? I am running Centos 6.8, and I can only find information on Centos 7.

I know that SQL Server on Linux is still in its early stages. I’m curious to see how it runs.

Comment: Assuming you have some blocker keeping you on 6.8, you could always just try the [installation procedures for RHEL 7.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-red-hat) and see what problems you come across. Personally, I have only used Ubuntu (both on its own and with Docker). FWIW, Microsoft hasn't uttered centOS a single time throughout this whole cycle, but most outside of Microsoft have lumped centOS and RHEL together.

Comment: I’m reluctant to move to CentOS 7 just for this exercise, as updating to a major version is never a trivial task. I have found Docker image which works well enough on my Mac, but the it appears that I will need CentOS 7 to run Docker as well …

Answer (score 1):

I installed developer edition on centos 7(Although, it was for RHEL), by referring : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-red-hat?view=sql-server-2017. Didn't get any difficulty in installation. I can use it now. documentation is good.